# How to make sbt run another consecutive command regardless of previous command's result?

Tags: scala, sbt

My tests are slow. Real slow. Like I can get another cup of coffee and reading some articles while waiting for them to finished slow. So I added this task to build.sbt just to alert me when my testing is finished.

```
lazy val alertMe = taskKey[Unit]("Alert me when testing is completed.")

alertMe in Test := {
  "say \"testing is completed\""!
}
```

Noted that I use say command on OS X. I then used this task like this.

```
;test ;alertMe
```

Voila! This works great.... only for successful testing. In case that any test case failed, test task return result as error, and alertMe is not invoked.

This behavior is pretty understandable. but I want my task, alert me, to run regardless of test task result. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can add `test` task in `alertMe` task, like:

```
lazy val alertMe = taskKey[Unit]("Alert me when testing is completed.")

alertMe := {
  Command.process("test", state.value)
  "say \"testing is completed\""!
}
```

usage: `sbt alertme`, it will run the `test` task and the shell command.

`Command.process` will execute the `test` task and without causing current task fail. so the commands always will be executed.

Comment: Command.process do the trick. However, normally I test with testOnly which takes params. So I made an InputTask like this instead.
`lazy val alertAfter = inputKey[Unit]("Alert when input task is completed.")

alertAfter := {
  val args: Seq[String] = DefaultParsers.spaceDelimited("<arg>").parsed
  Command.process(args.mkString(" "), state.value)
  "say \"testing is completed\""!
}`